# Table View does not display in storyboard nor simulator after created in storyboard

Tags: swift

I am beginner to swift. I have created a view controller with the table view and table view cell (dynamic table view). Why the table view is disappear after i run on simulator once or twice? I saw there is table view on the left side panel but I don't see it in editing area

[image: This image shows the storyboard of table view. I saw I have table view on the left side panel but I don't see it editing area]

Moreover, when I run it on simulator, it also does not show table view.

Comment: have you implemented nubmerOfSections and numberOfRows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You havent set the layout constraints for the tableview.

Select the table view from the view hierarchy. And go to the size inspector. Set x = 0 , y = 0 width = 400 and height = 600 for the table view.

After it Ctrl + Drag from tableview to view of viewcontroller.

[image]

And then hold shift and select top, bottom, leading and trailing space constraints. Like this:

[image]

This should solve your problem.